# Update String in objective C alert

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I put an NSString value in obj c alert, and I updated the string, it doesn’t seem to change the value in the alert but when I print it, it prints the changed value

```
NSString *Value = @"1";    // Alert = 1
NSlog(Value); // 1
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:Value message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert]; // Alert = 1
      UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
        [topController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    Value = @"2"; // Alert is still = 1
    NSlog(Value); // 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you provide for the title in the initialiser is copied to the alert's `title`.  Changing the value in the provided variable won't change the `title`. You can set a new value to `alert.title` directly.

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:Value message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert]; // Alert = 1
      UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
        [topController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

alert.title = @"2";
```

Comment: literally `alert.title=@"Some new title";`

Comment: No. It is a separate line after you create `alert`. You simply need to assign a new value to the `title` property.

Comment: If you want it to change over time, you need to set the title over time; each time `loader` changes you need to assign the new value to `title`.